# Audio sample not playing as expected on android11

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec, audiotrack, mediaextractor

I am trying to extract and play audio samples from a video file in Android 11. However, I have followed some tutorials from the official documentation, but it still doesn't work. All I get is noise for a shorter duration of the audio. Please check the code I am using to achieve this:

```
// This is how I get the audio samples
public ArrayList<byte[]> getAudio() {
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList<byte[]> audio = new ArrayList<>();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE));

    for (;;) {
        int size = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
        total_size += size;
        if (size < 0) { // no more data to read
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
            byte[] sample = new byte[2];
            for (int j = 0; j < sample.length; j++) {
                sample[j] = buffer.get();
            }
            audio.add(sample);
        }
        extractor.advance();
    }
    return audio;
}

Log.d("AudioTest", "total audio data size in bytes: " + total_size);

// This is how I play the audio
int SIZE = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
ArrayList<byte[]> audio = getAudio();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

track.play();
byte[] data = new byte[audio.size() * 2];
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < audio.size(); i++) {
    byte[] sample = audio.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < sample.length; j++, k++) {
        data[k] = sample[j];
    }
}
track.write(data, 0, data.length);

long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
Log.d("AudioTest", "that took: " + (duration / 1000) + "s");
```

I am facing an issue where my audio plays random noise for only 5 seconds. The `getAudio()` method retrieves only 487,831 bytes from the 15-second video file. Here are the details of the video file:

Frames:

- has-sdtp: 1
- track-id: 1
- level: 2048
- mime: video/avc
- frame-count: 461
- profile: 8
- language: und
- color-standard: 1
- display-width: 1920
- track-fourcc: 828601953
- csd-1: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9]
- color-transfer: 3
- durationUs: 15,382,033
- display-height: 1080
- width: 1920
- color-range: 2
- max-input-size: 3,145,748
- frame-rate: 30
- height: 1080
- csd-0: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=33 cap=33]

Samples:

- max-bitrate: 262,664
- isDMCMMExtractor: 1
- sample-rate: 48,000
- track-id: 2
- mime: audio/mp4a-latm
- profile: 2
- language: und
- aac-profile: 2
- track-fourcc: -1
- encoder-delay: 0
- durationUs: 15,402,666
- channel-count: 2
- bits-per-sample: 16
- encoder-padding: 48
- max-input-size: 524,308
- csd-0: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=2 cap=2]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audio is compressed using the Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) compression. You can see it from this line:
`mime: audio/mp4a-latm`.

But you are not decoding it. The `MediaExtractor` reads compressed samples while the `AudioTrack` expects decoded data (`AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` in your case).

You can use the [MediaCodec API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec) to decode the audio buffers that `MediaExtractor` reads.

By the way, you will not need to copy the decoded buffers into an array, just pass them to the `AudioTrack` as is.

Alternatively, you could detect the correct encoding and specify it when you set the `AudioTrack` up. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.Builder#setEncoding(int)) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.Builder).